# How to export data to an Xcode-project file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is it possible to export data to a Xcode-project file?

For example, I want to generate a new "hello.csv" file, using swift, that says "hello world"
into my Xcode Project locally but not in in-app document.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, no. If you want to use databases in code, use `.plist` (Preference List) files. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in Swift, but I do know how to in Objective-C.

To start off, make a PLIST file in Xcode, and add your data to it. Remember the key name values.

In your .m file, add this code to create an `NSMutableDictionary` that you can modify in code later:

`NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFile" ofType:@"plist"]];`

Then, to pull data out of the dictionary you made (`dict`), do something like this. Switch data types as necessary.

`NSString *helloWorld = (NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"yourKeyName"];`

(Note: the cast of `NSString*` is necessary because, otherwise, it will yell at you for having the incompatible type of `id`. In Swift, it's `object`. If you plan on modifying the string, then use `NSMutableString`.)

Then, to save it to the file, save the key/value pair in the dictionary:

`[dict setValue:helloWorld forKey:@"yourKeyName"];`

And finally, save the dictionary and overwrite the PLIST file.

`[dict writeToFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFile" ofType:@"plist"] atomically:YES];`

Note: the `writeToFile` method's `atomically` parameter is asking whether or not it has to write the file **right away** or **after it does whatever it needs to** (as in, it's not a high priority). I recommend setting this to `YES` or `true`.